# How can my where clause return results for unmatched values?

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have a table which has certain IDs, and values against them. If I pass a list of IDs in the where clause it will return only matching IDs, and discard the rest. How can I get the unmatched IDs also with a null value against them.

Table:
`select * from members;`

Result:

```
|member_id   |price   |
+--------------+-------
|   0        |1234    |
|   1        |99      |
+--------------+-------
```

However if we run this query, it won't return the unmatched values.
`select member_id,price from members where member_id in (0,1,2,3)`

How can I show IDs 2&3 as well, but with a null against them for price column?

Thanks!

Comment: Something's fishy - you have tags for mysql, oracle, and mariadb. Which is it? (Don't say "all of them" - that is not credible.)

Comment: Thanks @mathguy . I'm running on MySQL. I just thought to add several tags to seek help from wider community. I'll be mindful of this henceforth :)

Comment: Are (0,1,2,3) necessarily consecutive?  If so, so state; if not, change the example.

Comment: @Animesh - (A "wider community" is likely to give you _incorrect_ answers -- the databases are different enough for this to be a serious concern.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The values can't appear exclusively in the `where` clause; they must appear somehow in the `from` clause. You must create a view of some sort including those values. A common way is to use an Oracle-provided collection type and select from it, something like this:

```
select t.column_value as member_id, m.price
from   sys.odcinumberlist(0, 1, 2, 3) t left outer join members m
       on t.column_value = m.member_id
;

 MEMBER_ID      PRICE
---------- ----------
         0       1234
         1         99
         2           
         3
```

`odcinumberlist` is a collection data type (`varray of number`) defined in the `sys` package, provided by Oracle. When used in the `from` clause of a `select` statement, the values are in a column named `column_value`.

Whether this will work in "mariadb" (whatever that is), you will have to try and see. If it does not, you can try something more traditional, like

```
select t.member_id, m.price
from   (
         select 0 as member_id from dual union all
         select 1              from dual union all
         select 2              from dual union all
         select 3              from dual
       ) t
       left outer join members m on t.member_id = m.member_id
;
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use a LEFT JOIN for this:

```
SELECT m.member_id, m.price

FROM members m

LEFT JOIN members m2 ON m2.member_id = m.member_id

AND m2.member_id IN (0,1,2,3)

WHERE m2.member_id IS NULL
```

Comment: If the values 2 and 3 are not present in `members.member_id`, it doesn't matter if you outer-join the table to itself; the values still won't exist.